# How to store a heterogenous list of iterators or objects that can be converted to iterators that can be used multiple times?

Tags: rust

Is there a good way to store a heterogeneous list of iterators or objects that can be converted to iterators that can be used multiple times?  I've a situation where I'd like to iterate over a vector in multiple ways.  Most often, these indices will come from a range or another vector, but that's not a guarantee.  In addition, these indices will be used multiple times, so they must be reusable.  Is there a good way to accomplish this?  As one attempt, we have the code:

```
// Create a struct to hold a list of items that generate indices and a vector
struct Foo {
    data: Vec<f64>,
    index_list: Vec<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>>,
}

// Function that iterates over elements in the data
fn bar(f: &mut Foo) {
    for indices in &mut f.index_list {
        println!("Start of iteration");
        for i in indices {
            println!("{}", f.data[i])
        }
    }
}

// Test the routine
fn main() {
    let mut f = Foo {
        data: vec![0.1, 1.2, 2.3, 3.4],
        index_list: vec![
            Box::new((0..=1).into_iter()),
            Box::new(vec![2, 1, 3].into_iter()),
        ],
    };

    // Want these two functions to not consume the iterators and produce the
    // same result
    bar(&mut f);
    bar(&mut f);
}
```

This produces

```
Start of iteration
0.1
1.2
Start of iteration
2.3
1.2
3.4
Start of iteration
Start of iteration
```

which should be expected.  The iterators from the `Foo` structure are consumed the first time bar is called.  I would like to pass `f` to `foo` in an immutable fashion, so that multiple calls to `foo` will return the same result.  I also strongly do not want to collect the indices into a vector since the actual use case will involve a very long list of indices that themselves are very large.  As such, there are memory limitations that are not necessarily present in this example.

Anyway, removing the mutability above gives a compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: `&Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>` is not an iterator
  --> src/main.rs:14:18
   |
14 |         for i in indices {
   |                  ^^^^^^^ `&Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>` is not an iterator
   |
   = help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `&Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>`
   = note: `Iterator` is implemented for `&mut std::boxed::Box<dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = usize>>`, but not for `&std::boxed::Box<dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = usize>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `&Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>`
   = note: required by `into_iter`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Attempting to clone indices gives:

```
error[E0277]: `&Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>` is not an iterator
  --> src/main.rs:14:18
   |
14 |         for i in indices.clone() {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `&Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>` is not an iterator
   |
   = help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `&Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>`
   = note: `Iterator` is implemented for `&mut std::boxed::Box<dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = usize>>`, but not for `&std::boxed::Box<dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = usize>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `&Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>`
   = note: required by `into_iter`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

and attempting to use `cloned` on `index_list` gives:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `dyn Iterator<Item = usize>: Clone` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:12:40
   |
12 |     for indices in f.index_list.iter().cloned() {
   |                                        ^^^^^^ the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `dyn Iterator<Item = usize>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Clone` for `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `dyn Iterator<Item = usize>: Clone` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:12:20
   |
12 |     for indices in f.index_list.iter().cloned() {
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `dyn Iterator<Item = usize>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Clone` for `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Iterator` for `Cloned<std::slice::Iter<'_, Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `Cloned<std::slice::Iter<'_, Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>>>`
   = note: required by `into_iter`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store a list of functions that return those iterators:

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    data: Vec<f64>,
    index_list: Vec<&'a dyn Fn() -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>>,
}

fn bar(f: &mut Foo) {
    for indices in &mut f.index_list {
        println!("Start of iteration");
        for i in indices() {
            println!("{}", f.data[i])
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = Foo {
        data: vec![0.1, 1.2, 2.3, 3.4],
        index_list: vec![
            &|| Box::new((0..=1).into_iter()),
            &|| Box::new(vec![2, 1, 3].into_iter()),
        ],
    };

    bar(&mut f);
    bar(&mut f);
}
```

Comment: That works.  Thanks!  One question: What about the type system requires the closure?  I would have thought that either something that implements `IntoIterator` or calling `cloned` on the output from the iterator would have been possible.

Comment: @wyer33 The problem is that iterators are generally single-use-only. Once incremented it can not go backwards. Some iterators you can `.clone()` (not `.cloned()`, but `.clone()` on the iterator itself), but not all.